# Placeholder not wait up to user enters the one character

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a problem with a placeholder in html, when I am opening a page in internet explorer and samsung default browsers, the placeholder disappears when I focus on the field.

In other browers it is working fine.

Sample html : `<input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email Address'>`

Comment: The way placeholder work depend on the broswer, some wait until the first character is enter, other remove it on focus. There is no fix for that. The only thing you can do is use a custom placeholder...

Comment: Thanks for reply. i am also try this custom placeholder(https://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/) i got a problem with this also when i am focus on text field placeholder disabled in IE and Some sansumng default browsers. can u please help .... –

Comment: Here is the my sample fiddle link ---http://jsfiddle.net/thiru715/5LEW6/2/
open on different browers problem in IE & samsung default browser and focus on text field.

Answer (score 1):

[This custom placeholder](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/) will add a placeholder as described in the documentation.

It will be consistent in all modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
i am also try this custom placeholder i got a problem with this also when i am focus on text field placeholder disabled in IE and Some sansumng default browsers.
can u please help ....

Comment: some demo code on jsfiddle or any specification what you have tried would be helpfull.

Comment: Here is the my sample fiddle link ---http://jsfiddle.net/thiru715/5LEW6/2/
open on different browers problem in IE & samsung default browser and focus on text field.

Comment: you have to implement jQuery into your page as well, before the whole code. Then you implement the placeholder function (i recommend using a sepperate file) and AFTER this you can initialze it.

Comment: you can also have a look in the demo.html there it works, I just recommend a newer version of jquery, which you can find here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: i am using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
even though i am not getting in IE10+ and Samsung default browers on focus on text field

Comment: have you put the placeholder function above the initialising ?

Comment: Hi frieder,
thanks for reply. 
I am added the header and fotters.
please open the jsfiddle (-jsfiddle.net/thiru715/5LEW6/2) in IE and other browers and focus on text field you find out the problem ...
thanks,
Thiru.